Inline member initialization with values of other aggregate initialized members
Is such code with the aggregate initialization a valid C++ program?
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

struct Sheet {
  const int c[2]{};
  const int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(c), std::end(c), 0);
};

int main() {
  Sheet sheet0;
  Sheet sheet1{{10}};
  Sheet sheet2{{10, 20}};
  std::cout << sheet0.sum << "\n";
  std::cout << sheet1.sum << "\n";
  std::cout << sheet2.sum << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
// 0
// 10
// 30

This is a struct with the Excel sheet like behavior: a user initializes cells with some values, if a user does not initialize sum then it gets the computed sum of the cell values.
I am not sure that inline member initialization and not zero initialization happens at skipped members in aggregate initialization.
I expected that the statement
Sheet sheet2{{10, 20}};

would be the same as
Sheet sheet2{{10, 20}, {}};

and output 0, but my program runs showed that they result in different outputs 30 and 0.

@3CxEZiVlQ Why do you think it might be invalid?

"Is such code with the aggregate initialization a valid C++ program?" -- Aggregate initialization is valid in a C++ program, so I conclude that your text is overly terse, unlikely to be found by the next person with the same question. Try using a full paragraph to ask your question instead of trying to squeeze everything into a simple sentence. (That's "simple" in the grammatical sense; there is only one verb.)

@songyuanyao The initialization order, not sure that inline member initialization and not zero initialization happens at skipped members in aggregate initialization.

For Sheet sheet2{{10, 20}};, the data member sum will be initialized by its default member initializer. It's not same as Sheet sheet2{{10, 20}, {}}; where sum will be initialized by {}.

For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly
initialized element is initialized as follows:

If the element has a default member initializer, the element is initialized from that initializer. (since C++11)

Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list.

Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.
struct S
{
    int a;
    const char* b;
    int c;
    int d = b[a];
};

// initializes ss.a with 1,
//             ss.b with "asdf",
//             ss.c with the value of an expression of the form int{} (that is, 0),
//         and ss.d with the value of ss.b[ss.a] (that is, 's')
S ss = {1, "asdf"};




In detail, for Sheet sheet0;, data member c and sum will be initialized by their default member initializers. The 2 elements of c will be zero.
For Sheet sheet1{{10}};, c will be initialized by {10}, sum will be initialized by its default member initializer. As {10} contains only 1 initializer which is less than the number of members of c as 2, the 1st element of c will be 10 and the 2nd one will be zero.
For Sheet sheet2{{10, 20}};, c will be initialized by {10, 20}, sum will be initialized by its default member initializer. As the effect the 1st element of c will be 10 and the 2nd one will be 20.

So the order is explicit member initialization, otherwise default member initialization, otherwise empty list initialization. A bit complicated but exactly is what I need.

@3CxEZiVlQ Yes, if explicit initializer provided, then it'll be used, note if the number of initializer is less then remaining members will be initialized by empty list initialization. If no initializer then default member initializer will be considered.

There is nothing wrong with the program. Behavior is well-defined and guaranteed to be what you observe.
If no initializer is given for an aggregate element in aggregate initialization, then it is initialized as if by = {} unless it has a default member initializer. Either way, elements of c that do not have a corresponding initializer in the aggregate initialization will therefore be initialized to 0.
sum is declared later than c in the class and its initialization is therefore sequenced after the initialization of c. Because a default member initializer is given, that one will be used to initialize it and because of the sequencing, c is already initialized and usable at that point.
